# mongo php search query is not working properly?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am looking to get the count of records in table. When i try to search manually it is showing 1 record. But when i try to search dynamically it is showing zero records.

below is the code i tried:

```
$conn = new Mongo($server);
$_db = $conn->{$db};
$collection = $_db->{$collection};
//$query=array('ci_courrgate'=>1); working fine  o/p :1
$query=array('ci_courrgate'=>$id); not working   o/p:0
// $query=array('ci_courrgate'=>'"'.$id.'"'); not working   o/p:0
echo $collection->count($query);
```

in mongo my record is as below

```
{ "_id" : 11,"ci_courrgate" : "1"}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$id`

Comment: the value of $id is 1

Comment: When quering MongoDb, it is very specific on the [data type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) used for querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i changed my code it works fine. As you can see my record in db is in double quotes. Then that would be consider as string. So i changed my query as below

```
$query=array('ci_courrgate'=>(string)$id); working   o/p:1
```